# Не могу обновить таблицу

Tags: c#, mysql

Не могу при вставке в таблицу resultsell обновить значение в таблице products. Суть такая: я при вставке в таблицу resultsell должен отнять 1 у определенного товара в таблице products. Выполняю через программу. Однако выбивает ошибку как на скрине ниже[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом если я делаю update через запрос в Workbench то все работает а через тригер не хочет. Кто сталкивался подскажите в чем может быть проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `DecrementQuantify`()
BEGIN
Update products
SET QuantityProducts=QuantityProducts-1 
WHERE idProducts=(
SELECT idProducts 
FROM resultsell
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
END
```

Comment: С процедурой всё нормально. А как именно и откуда Вы её вызываете "через программу"?

Comment: @Akina я сделал прогу которая типо имитирует работу магазина по продаже консолей. И когда я работаю в форме покупки продукта я вставляю в таблицу resultsell запись. А если я вроде как купил какой то товар то в таблице products должно отняться 1 штука товара у определенного продукта.Вставка работает. Настраиваю тригер, ошибка. Хотя если я напрямую в бд через Mysql workbench напишу запрос на update то все нормально отнимется

Comment: *Настраиваю тригер, ошибка* Так процедура используется из триггера? Правильно послали... в триггере вместо подзапроса должно быть вульгарное `WHERE idProducts=NEW.idProducts`. А ещё правильнее - передавать это NEW.idProducts в процедуру как параметр (и шоб я понял, нахрена тут вообще она нужна, эта процедура...).

Comment: Распишите по шагам все, что нужно для воспроизведения ошибки: таблица, процедура, триггер, код вызова из C#. Все сообщения об ошибках выложите в виде текста.